# JTree out of Hashmap

Tags: java, jtree

I have a (Hash)Map called treefile with sample content:

```
treefile.put("Adhesive Tapes", "Mechanical  Components|Mechanical Incidentals|Fastening Elements");
treefile.put("Bayonet Fitting, Snap Locks, Spring Locks", "Mechanical  Components|Mechanical Incidentals|Fastening Elements");
```

The value of treefile is the path for the JTree and the key is the product. 
I'm iterating over the Map with:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : file.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String values[] = entry.getValue().split("\\|");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode keyn = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(key);
        for (String k : values) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode n = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(k);
            keyn.add(n);
        }
        top.add(keyn);
}

DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(firstn);
```

The problem now is, that the JTree shows me each "top.add(keyn)" as a new node instead of adding it to the existing one...

How can i fix this? So that if the node exists its added to this one?

I want to see the JTree like:

```
Root
|
Mechanical Components
    |
    Mechanical Incidentals
        |
        Product A
        |
        Product B
```

and not like its now:

```
Root
|
Mechanical Components
    |
    Mechanical Incidentals
    |       |
    |      Product A
    Mechanical Incidentals
            |
           Product B
```

Comment: At the bottom of your question, under the shaded keyword rectangles, is an “edit” link.  Please use that to update your question with a simple textual mock-up of what you expect the JTree’s content to look like.  I have a guess, but I’d rather not answer without a clear understanding of what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of blindly adding new nodes, you need to look for a matching ancestor node as you add leaf nodes.

Your keys represent leaf nodes, that is, nodes which should have no children, so you definitely should not be doing `keyn.add(n)`.  Rather, you should create nodes *as needed* for the tree path represented by the split value.  The “as needed” part is important if you want to be able to place multiple nodes under the same parent.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : file.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String values[] = entry.getValue().split("\\|");

    DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = top;
    for (String k : values) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode n = null;

        Enumeration<?> e = parent.children();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            n = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();
            if (k.equals(n.getUserObject())) {
                // Existing node matches; use that one.
                break;
            }
            n = null;
        }

        if (n == null) {
            // No existing node matches;  add it.
            n = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(k);
            parent.add(n);
        }

        parent = n;
    }

    DefaultMutableTreeNode keyn = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(key);
    parent.add(keyn);
}
```

There are more efficient ways to do this.  For example, instead of relying on DefaultMutableTreeNodes, you can create your own implementation of TreeNode which uses a `LinkedHashMap<String, TreeNode>` internally, which would allow you to look up a TreeNode for a particular String more easily.

Also, be aware that not all Map implementations maintain consistent order.  Your `Map<String, String>` should be a SortedMap or LinkedHashMap.

Comment: thank you, your solution worked perfectly as expected!!
Problem is that this Map comes from an other class/system and i can not be sure that it's sorted... Can i sort the Map beforehand?

Comment: Yes, quite easily: `Map<String, String> sorted = new TreeMap<>(Collator.getInstance()); sorted.putAll(file);`